# SAS Proc SQL how to convert from Number to Character

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am very new to SAS.

I want to convert Number to Character.

basically I want to use to_char function

so I try

```
proc sql;
select put(A.column,$11.) as new_column
from table A
quit;
```

This causing error,

what is appropriate way to convert Number to Character???

Comment: Character formats (the ones starting the `$`) are applied to character values.  You need to use a numeric format, such as `11.` or `Z11.` if you want for apply it to your numeric values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close - you just need a numeric format, eg:

```
proc sql;
select put(A.column,11.) as new_column
  from table A;
```

(You also needed a closing semicolon)

See documentation:  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0mlfb88dkhbmun1x08qbh5xbs7e.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en